# Iterate Over Multiple Start-Stop Values in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a number, `l`, and I'd like to split it up into roughly equal `n` chunks. For example:

```
l = 11
n = 3
step = 1 + l // n

for start in range(0, l, step):
    stop = min(l, start+step)
    print(start, stop)
```

In this case, the first chunk (chunk `0`)  goes from 0 to 4 (5 elements), the next chunk (chunk `1`) goes from 4 to 8 (5 elements), and the last chunk (chunk `2`) is slightly smaller and goes from 8 to 11 (4 elements). Of course, the values of `l` and `n` may vary but both values will always be positive integers and `n` will always be smaller than `l`.

What I need to do is to generate a list that will iterate through each chunk in a round-robin fashion and append some chunk information to a list. The list should contain a tuple of the chunk number (i.e., `0`, `1`, or `2`) and the next available start value in that chunk (until that chunk is exhausted as controlled by the `stop` value). So, the output list would be:

```
[(0,0), (1,4), (2,8), (0,1), (1,5), (2,9), (0,2), (1,6), (2,10), (0,3), (1,7)]
```

Note that the last chunk has one last element than the first two chunks. Whatever the solution is, it needs to work for any `l` and `n` (as long as both values are positive integers and `n` is always smaller than `l`). For simplicity, you can assume that `l` will be less than 100,000,000.

What is the best way to generate this list?

Comment: That last grouping shouldn't exist: you've already covered the 4-8 chunking in the first group.

Comment: Ohh, you're right! There should only be 11 elements in the list. Updated now

Answer (score 1):

Use two loops for the two levels of your problem.  The outer loop runs the starting point through all numbers in `range(step)`.  From there, use that value as the starting point for the inner loop you already wrote.  Note that you have to adjust your output: you're printing (start, stop) values, when your requested output has (chunk#, start) values.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I guess I'd have to add in some stopping criteria to break out of both for loops? I figured that there must be some way to accomplish this via itertools

Comment: You can get the stopping criteria with a straightforward `for` loop.  Once you code those loops (`enumerate` will give you the chunk #), collapse them into a list comprehension.  Also look up "chunking a list" for a check on your algebra; you can steal some of their arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, using generators:

```
from itertools import islice, zip_longest, cycle

def chunk(it, size):
    it = iter(it)
    return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(it, size)), ())

def generate(l, n):
    c, step = cycle(range(n)), l // n + (l % n != 0)
    yield from ((next(c), v) for vals in zip_longest(*chunk(range(l), step)) for v in vals if v is not None)

l = 11
n = 3

out = [*generate(l, n)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 4), (2, 8), (0, 1), (1, 5), (2, 9), (0, 2), (1, 6), (2, 10), (0, 3), (1, 7)]
```

---

For:

```
l = 9
n = 3
```

The output is:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 3), (2, 6), (0, 1), (1, 4), (2, 7), (0, 2), (1, 5), (2, 8)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the output. Please see correct (updated) output in OP

Comment: No, there should only be 9 elements when `l=9`. Your answer has 10 elements

Comment: I'd fix the `step` calculation. Would not just give a better result but also allow simpler code.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I rewrote it completely, using `itertools`, now it generates evenly spaced chunks.

Comment: @slaw Reworked my answer with itertools, now should generate better results.